# Why is this logic used to find line of symmetry of zeroes

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Consider this problem:

Let F(x) be a function in x and and let if x' is a zero of F(x) , then 1-x' is also a zero of F(x). Then it is to be proved that zeroes of F(x) are symmetric about x=1/2.

Now, what i do in such kind of questions is : I put x=1-x and I get line of symmetry as x=1/2.( something like  this was told by the instructor in school ) but i don't know the logic why is it done and i am willing to learn it. So, can you please help me with that.

> This question has been on my mind since a quite long time and it's a genuine and meaningful question( I think). But if someone thinks that I am not making much sense or I need to add explanation/details. I am happy to add it.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what does it _mean_ to say the zeroes are symmetric about $x=1/2$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Suppose I move leftwards on x-axis ( starting from x=1/2) and at a distance d i get a 0 of F(x), then if I move a distance d rightwards starting from x=1/2 , I will surely get a 0 of F(x) after reaching distance d. This is what I mean.

Comment: Okie dokie. In other words, "if $F(\frac12+d)=0$ then $F(d-\frac12)=0$". Now you're set: Suppose $F(x)=0$. Choose $d$ so $x=\frac12+d$. Then $F(\frac12-d)=0$. But $\frac12-d=1-x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If F(1/2+d) =0 then F(1/2-d)=0( not F(d-1/2)=0, I think that is the correct implication by my statement.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you please reply to my comment above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given this property :

- If $F(x')=0$, then $F(1-x')=0$.

Now, let $x'=\frac12+d$ where $d$ is a real number and suppose it is a root of $F$.

Then we have $F\left( \frac12 + d\right)=0$, by the property that is given to us,

$$F\left( 1-\left(\frac12+d \right)\right)=F\left(\frac12-d \right)=0.$$

Hence, we can conclude that the zeros are symmetrical about $x=\frac12$.

---

Now, in general, if the axis of symmetry of the zeros is $m$, that is

$$F\left( m+d\right) = F(m-d)=0,$$

Let $x'=m+d$, then $m-d=m-(x'-m)=2m-x'$ and the condition can be rewritten as

- If $F(x')=0$, then $F(2m-x')=0$.